# behavior of sql query with OFFSET and fetch clause in postgres/oracle with deletion of records

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I have a query like :

```
select * from mytable order by mycol_1 OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Now, if in this iteration ,I delete several records out of the 10 records fetched by above query and then run :

```
 select * from mytable order by mycol_1 OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Will I be getting the real next 10 records or does the SQL engine shift up some rows and thus skip some of the rows ?

Comment: Yes, that always happens with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. Use keyset pagination for better guarantees and better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example: if you have 20 rows (let's suppose that those are ordinal numbers from 1 to 20) and delete e.g. 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 and then run your 2nd statement (`offset 10`): it will "skip" values 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 (which make offset = 10) and return values from 16 onwards.

If you again use `offset 0`, you'd get 1,3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 as result which means that nothing will be skipped (except, of course, rows that are deleted, they don't exist any more).

Basically, it means that you can omit `OFFSET` entirely and work with `FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY` option.

---

By the way, you're right in using the `order by` clause; I've seen people "hoping" that query will automagically return rows they *think" SQL will return, but - without the `order by` clause, that's unpredictable.

Comment: I didn't get your currently clause, is the output of the next select dependent on whether delete was done in the same transaction or some other transaction .

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then it doesn't matter, as long as you're in the same **session**. Deleted rows are ... well, *deleted*, they don't exist in a table and you don't see them any more. If they were deleted in someone else's session, then it depends on whether they committed DELETE (so you won't see those rows any more) or not (so you'll still see them, until they commit).

Comment: I have 20 records, I fetch first 10 records, delete all the fetched 10 records in a different transaction(commit also), then ask sql engine to fetch the next 10 records (offset 10)

Comment: Ah, sorry! I missed (not being careful) that your second SELECT has offset **10** rows; thought it was 0 (as in the first statement). So: if you have 20 rows (let's suppose that those are ordinal numbers from 1 to 20) and delete e.g. 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 and then run your 2nd statement: it will "skip" values 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 (which make offset = 10) and return values from 16 onwards.

Comment: Yes; I modified what I wrote above; better to be *there* than as a comment.

Comment: But if I adjust the offset of the next select, by pushing it back by the number of deleted rows, then I will not skip any  rows.. ??

Comment: You mean, if you again use offset 0? Then you'd get 1,3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 as result which means that nothing will be skipped (except, of course, rows that are deleted, they don't exist any more)

Comment: yes, that essentially translates to use of offset as 0 every time, you fetch first 10 , process them, delete them and then next 10, with offset 0 and so on.. and this is what I need. and no rows are skipped ..

Comment: Right; but, do you need to use the OFFSET at all, then? Wouldn't FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY be enough? Process them, delete them, and then fetch another 10 rows?